# Center aligning a table in ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

Ok so I want to center align this table. The html of the table looks like this.

```
%table
  %tbody{id: "table"}
   - @student.module_lists.each do |module_list|
    %tr{id: "module_list_#{module_list.id}"}
      %td= module_list.title
      %td= link_to 'Show', module_list
      %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_module_list_path(module_list)
      %td= link_to 'Destroy', module_list, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }, :remote => true
```

I added in an id for the table and used this CSS.

```
#table{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 100px;
}
```

Which, on other websites seemed to work for others, however I just end up with a black dot in the middle of my screen, not the table. And if I add a border to this table, the border goes around the black dot in the center of my screen. I'm not sure if this is caused because the table is links or what not, but any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why do you wrap `<li>` around the `<tr>`s

Comment: I'm new to this so let me know if its wrong/how it should be done. thanks

Comment: if you just try to center the table, put the id on `%table{id: "table"}`, you don't need that `<li>`, which is where that black dot coming from

Comment: Ah yes thanks that got rid of the dot. Table is still to the left though

Comment: "Tip: Center aligning has no effect if the width property is not set (or set to 100%)" [source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Comment: Just added, no change though

Comment: update your question with your new codes. here's what i have in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/936uyvvq/)